# Determining the equivalent resistance

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

It is required to find R=V/I given that \$V_{gd}\$ is zero.

Honestly, I don't know where to start. I don't think there is a current in the \$R_s\$ and \$R_g\$ resistors because the current has no way of coming back.(is that right?)

Comment: You'd think current source is dependent on \$V_{GD}\$ voltage across the resistor on the left-hand side of the circuit, not \$V_{GS}\$. What do you mean find R, which one? Input resistance? This is like a hybrid-pi model of a mosfet, with s and d nodes are switched

Comment: I guess it is referring to the equivalent resistance since it is V/I.

Comment: Any clues on how to solve it?

Comment: That circuit is rubbish - clear to my eyes is the deletion of an input voltage source and it being replaced with a short. Also the current source refers to \$V_{gs}\$ which means the drain and source must be labelled incorrectly. What's going on - is it me being stoopid (again)? Also, what are you trying to find the equivalent resistance of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: it has been a while since I looked at this kind of circuit problem, so I think I made a mistake in defining \$V_{gs}\$, but it doesn't matter, and here's why:

Firstly, there can be no current in the loop that has \$R_{s}\$ and \$R_{g}\$ in it.

As for the current source: it is in parallel with \$V\$ and \$R_{DS}\$, so if you do have any current from your current supply, it has to go through the voltage supply and can't go through the resistor \$R_{DS}\$ or the voltage across the resistor would be higher than the voltage supply in parallel with it \$V\$ and that breaks all the rules.  If you need to verify this with some equations/analysis, do mesh analysis on the right half of the circuit and verify that the current supply can't put any current in \$R_{DS}\$.

So you're left with a voltage supply (\$V\$) and a resistor (\$R_{DS}\$) in parallel.  The only current that can go through the resistor has to come from the voltage supply.

To get the equivalent resistance \$R = V/I\$, first rewrite:

\$g_{m}*V_{gs} = -g_{m}*V\$,

since node D and G are the same, and \$V_{DS}\$ is equivalent to \$-V\$.

Next, write out \$I\$ as the sum of the negative current from the current source plus the current from \$V/R_{DS}\$:

\$I = g_{m}*V + V/R_{DS} \$

Next, substitute our derived \$I\$ into the equation \$R=V/I\$ and simplify to get the answer:

\$R = V/I = V/( g_{m}*V + V/R_{DS}) = 1/(g_{m} + 1/R_{DS})\$

And that is the equivalent resistance.

Comment: I made a mistake in typing, its \$V_{gd}\$ =0

Comment: The answer is R=\$R_{DS}\$||\$1/g_{m}\$ which does not make sense

Comment: @user29568: Could you define better what exactly you expect from the answer?  I did all the analysis I could do, but I don't know exactly what you mean by "It is required to find R=V/I", etc.  What are you trying to find?

Comment: Why does it not make sense?  gm is a transconductance. It has units 1/ohms.

Comment: I was confused by the way the question was phrased, but I think I just submitted a complete and correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If V<sub>gd</sub> is zero, then V<sub>gs</sub> is the same as V<sub>ds</sub>.

That means the VCCS acts just like a resistor with resistance 1/g<sub>m</sub>.

Now you just have two resistors in parallel.

Which gives you the same answer as Bob got, but maybe with an explanation that is more intuitive (for some people, others might like Bob's better).